# Postgres 10: raise exception or perform an update depending on select query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

```
UNIT:
    integer id (PKEY)
    varchar symbol 

OPERATION:
    integer id (PKEY)
    integer unit_id (FKEY to UNIT table) accepts null
```

I need to construct some script based on select query result, but I don't know how to write it properly.

What I need to achieve, written in pseudo-sql:

```
if (select count(*) from UNIT where symbol = 'some_text' = 0)
    then raise exception 'not found!'
else 
    update OPERATION set unit_id = (select id from unit where symbol = 'rg' limit 1) where unit_id = null;
```

So, when UNIT table does not contain any records with symbol = "some_text", an exception should be raised.

Otherwise, an update on OPERATION table on unit_id column should be pefrormed - null values should be replaced with first UNIT record id value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_operation_unit(IN CHARACTER VARYING(250) symbol_text) RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ [...] $$
```

This function could run exactly the pseudo code you described above.